# Where to keep the old data entered using a form in MS Word?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word

I have a form embedded in the MS Word. The form is activated using a button command. The user pushes the button to open the form and then modifies the text fields in the form. The text entered in the form are printed in the same word document.

The problem for me that I am finding a way to keep and retrieve the previous data entered in the text fields. When the form is opened it should contain the previously entered data.

How and where I can keep the previous form data?

Comment: How about storing the info in hidden page?

Comment: could you please give me some more hints ?

Comment: You fetch the data from the form controls and then post them with a tag on a page. Then select the page, format the Font to Hidden (and you got a hidden page). You can still interact with this page via VBA. Put the "data read" code at the doc open event. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Variables collection of the Document object.

You can create/overwrite them easily, naming is flexible, they can each hold a large amount of data, and they are not easily seen or damaged by ordinary end users.

Comment: Thanks !! The problem is solved with your suggestion.